# Can $A$ be singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

$A^2 + A + I= 0$

Can $A$ be singular? Justify your answer.

I do not know where to start.

Comment: Do you have the Caley-Hamilton theorem available?

Comment: @HenningMakholm You don't need the Caley-Hamilton theorem. After all, we already have a polynomial for which $A$ is a zero.

Comment: @OscarCunningham: Hmm, you're right. I had a vastly overcomplicated route in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it:
$$\eqalign{A^2+A+I=O\quad
  &\Rightarrow\quad (A-I)(A^2+A+I)=O\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad A^3=I\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad (\det A)^3=1\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad \det A\ne0\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad\hbox{$A$ is invertible}.\cr}$$

Comment: $A^3=I$ so $A^2$ is the inverse of $A$

Comment: @orangeskid Yes indeed.  As shown in other answers, there are lots of ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a start: if you rewrite your equation as $A(A+I)+I = 0$, or
$$ A[-(A+I)] = I $$
then you see that the quantity in brackets must be the inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a singular matrix is that it is not invertible. What would determine whether A can be invertible?